# Use disabled input to display data

Tags: angularjs, input, formatting, decimal, disabled-input

To get a consistent look and feel of both input and output views I am trying to use an disabled input element to display model data/values.

The value is a calculated temperature value and has several decimal digits. Since that does not make sense from an engineer's point of view I want to limit the displayed decimal digits to a certain amount (let's say two digits, the displayed value does not need to be rounded).

Example:

- calculated value: 123.123456
- value to display: 123.12

I read around the Internet and found many suggestions using input's `step` attribute like

```
step=".01"
```

to limit the decimal digits. There seem to be many people doing it that way, but it does not work for me.

I think view and data model need to kept separated so adapting the model data (like converting the values to strings or using `toFixed()`) does not seem to be a nice solution. The view should be able to format the data itself, not changing the data model and should have reading access in this case only.

There is [a filter for doing this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) when accessing model data through the `{{  }}` notation. But this does not seem to be applicable straight out of the way.

So, do you have any suggestions about limiting the decimal numbers?

For the sake of investigation and in order to provide a working sample code I created a [Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NAvBRx?editors=1010).

Comment: What has this got to do with Angular Material?

Comment: @camden_kid: Changed tag to `angularjs`